# Implementing c++ Callback using Qt Signal and Slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a library which has following interface and callback.
I wanted to Implent it using QT Signal and Slot.

Is is possible to replace IWifiCameraDiscovery with Signal and slot

```
class IWifiCameraDiscovery
{
    public:

      virtual int InitialiseWiFiDiscovery(IWifiCameraEnumerationCallback*) = 0;


      virtual void UnInitialiseWiFiDiscovery() = 0; 


      virtual int   EnumerateWiFiDevice() = 0;  
 };

  class IWifiCameraEnumerationCallback
  {
  public:

virtual void onWiFiDeviceDiscovered( WiFiDeviceInfo* pDeviceInfo,unsigned short nNoOfDevice) = 0;   


virtual void onDiscoveryTimeout() = 0;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a quite straightforward way.

```
class IWifiCameraDiscovery
{
public:
    virtual int InitialiseWiFiDiscovery() = 0;    
    virtual void UnInitialiseWiFiDiscovery() = 0;     
    virtual int EnumerateWiFiDevice() = 0; 

signals: 
    void onWiFiDeviceDiscovered(WiFiDeviceInfo* pDeviceInfo, unsigned short nNoOfDevice);   
    void onDiscoveryTimeout();
};
```

In your implementation, instead of calling the callbacks directly:

```
callback.onWiFiDeviceDiscovered(pDevInfo, x);
```

You would emit a signal:

```
emit onWiFiDeviceDiscovered(pDevInfo, x);
```

And you would use `QObject::connect` to connect these signals to your actual receivers (slots) on the other end. Be aware that emitting a signal is more expensive than calling a virtual function.

Comment: you mean to say I dont require IWifiCameraEnumerationCallback interface for call back?

Comment: How do client program implement this ?

Comment: No such requirement, signals are a sort of ducktype interface (they are checked at runtime). The client creates a Qt slot and connects your signal to it. You may want to try and experiment with signals and slots before changing your code to use them.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple example

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(200, 120);

    QPushButton *quit = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"), this);
    quit->setGeometry(62, 40, 75, 30);
    quit->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));

    connect(quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

you can use like this

```
class IWifiCameraDiscovery
{      
 public slots:
    void UnInitialiseWiFiDiscovery();

 signals:
    void EnumerateWiFiDevice();
}
```

Comment: please ask further details if any?

Comment: i know this example but i wanted how to use signal and slot for my case